# Shall in If-Clause

Tags: grammar

Can 'shall' be used in If Clause? I read a site that says it can, but it was unfamiliar to me. I know that 'should' can, but I don't know whether 'shall' can be used in it. If it can be used in If clause, what meaning does it make?

Comment: Does the site where you saw it give examples?

Comment: Yes, It did. Could you diagnose this situation?

Comment: I think 'shall' just creates a future time?

Comment: I was expecting you to _tell_ us what examples the site gave - otherwise we can't comment on them!

Comment: If the weather shall clear up, I'll go with you.

Comment: This was its only sentence of 'shall'.

Comment: And I'm sorry;;;.  T.T

Comment: _If the weather shall clear up, I'll go with you_. That is not standard English usage. We would use the present tense, illogical as it may seem. _If the weather clears up..._

Comment: I understand. But I sometimes saw 'will' with 'if'. When do we use 'will' with 'if'?

Comment: When it's a question of someone _being willing_ to do something. _If you will wash the dishes, I'll dry them and put them away._

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you.